# Exception while invoking a test driver

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mbunit, gallio

> Error loading SomeGallioTestProject.dll: An exception occurred while invoking a test driver.

I have this visual studio 2010 solution which contains to separate test projects.

They use MBUnit and Gallio for the test framework.

Previously both test projects used to run when Test/Run/All Tests in Solution was invoked.

Now only one of the test projects is running, and the error shown above is returned for the other project.

I have created new installation of visual studio with mbunit/gallio 3.4.14 to attempt to resolve the problem and it has made no difference.

Changing the processor type generates a similar error but identifies a mismatch, so in that case I am getting a different type of error.

Running the tests with Icarus allows the test suite to run, although Typemock is not correctly initialised in that case.

I cannot find any other files to indicate the cause of the exception and am after ideas to help identify the cause of the error, or even the mechanism to fix if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the projects/mbunit/gallio dlls of different .net runtime versions?

Try building them all against .net 3.5 framework.

Or, If all are targeted to .net 4.0, maybe try changing

```
<startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

to:

```
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
</startup>
```

in the test project's `app.config`

Comment: I suspect it may be related to the issue as the problem is directly related to the installation of Revit 2014 which includes .NET 4.5.  I don't have an app.config as such as the item I am working with is a class library.

Comment: app.config can be added to a class library also.